# What do the TinyGPS++ output parameters mean?

Tags: gps, tinygps

TinyGPS++ give many output parameters. Where can I find explanation what do all output parameters mean? I don't understand what is the meaning of the following parameters:

> Course Speed Card  Distance Course Car

[image]

UPD

**2365** is distance to London

**wnw** is the direction to London: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_the_compass#Compass_point_names

**0.00** - Vertical speed?

**0.06** - Horizontal speed?

**294.06** - ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see when you look at the source code of the FullExample.ino that is part of the TinyGPS++ library, the values you marked are:

1. Course Speed Card*: The current speed (in km/h), course (in degrees) and cardinal course (which is the course translated to a cardinal direction on a compass, i.e. N,S,E,W, NE, NNW, etc.) of the GPS receiver (i.e. you).
2. Distance Course Card**: The distance (in km) and course and cardinal course to some location or waypoint (London in this example).

After the information you added in your edit, this means the following:

- 0.00 is your current course over ground (i.e. due North)
- 0.06 is current current speed over ground (i.e. as good as stationary)
- N is your current cardinal course
- 2365 is the distance to London (km)
- 294.06 is the bearing to London from your location
- WNW is the cardinal bearing to London

* this is also known as SOG (Speed Over Ground) and COG (Course Over Ground, which is used in (aero)nautical navigation) or Bearing.

** this is also known as DTG and CTS (Distance to Go and Course to Steer) when navigating to a GPS waypoint.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I don't understand is why my GPS module is always moving to North and current course over ground is always 0. My GPS module doesn't move at all, so I understand that variable slow speed 0.06 is due to some errors. In this case the course and direction supposed to change randomly, but they are remain constant: 0.00 and N.

Comment: It might be your GPS module is only able to calculate a course if it moves more than a certain distance/speed. What I have seen from various GPS systems, this is normal behaviour.